# Local files (xampp) using a remote mysql - very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, xampp, performance-testing, php-5.6

i have a local xampp, with php application runing on php5.6 and data base mysql are remote.

the issue is my application open very slow on my browser, is there an way to improve speed ?

mysql is on ssd server (fast)...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's always going to be slower over a remote connection. How much really depends on a number of factors related to your connection, not really to MySql.

Few things to consider - do you really need to be working off the remote db? Can you use a local copy and sync changes later? Might even be faster to have your code remote and suffer the slightly longer save times when updating your code. Highly situational though depending on your dev set-up.

Another option which would be a bit more complicated is to set up your local db as a read-only slave and at least that way you get more of async update -- i.e., your local db may lag behind remote master a bit but any reads you do locally will be back to your "native" local performance. You would have the additional complexity of setting up Master/Slave replication with different connections for read/write but that may be something you want to do for production anyway. (You can do master/master but I wouldn't recommend it over a remote connection.)

Comment: Hi ldg,
the objective is protect part of my application from new join programmers,
so, i encrypt some files (db config for eg.) and i pretend to offer just files and database remote to him work...

but my friend told me that with Models a programer can create a modal of database with it... 

My real objective is liberate code enough for the work and enough to protect all application...

the last programmer that i hired, after i release the code and database he gone way... with almost 2 years of work.